# SeriLog filter endpoints are not ignored

Tags: serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

I have the following filter configuration setup for serilog:

```json
"Filter": [
  {
    "Name": "ByExcluding",
    "Args": {
      "expression": "RequestPath = '/api/maat'"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "ByExcluding",
    "Args": {
      "expression": "RequestPath = '/swagger%'"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "ByExcluding",
    "Args": {
      "expression": "RequestPath = '/hangfire%'"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "ByExcluding",
    "Args": {
      "expression": "RequestPath = '/serilog-ui%'"
    }
  }
]
```

This excludes the `api/maat` endpoint and endpoints pertaining to hangfire, swagger and serilog-ui. Unfortunately this only works for `api/maat`, and does not work for the other endpoints. I'm unsure why.

If i'm hitting all endpoints the console shows the following:
[image]

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing the issue by moving it all into a singular filter, instead of spread out into multiple, and by using `StartsWith`:

```json
"Filter": [
  {
    "Name": "ByExcluding",
    "Args": {
      "expression": "RequestPath = '/api/maat' or StartsWith(RequestPath, '/swagger') or StartsWith(RequestPath, '/hangfire') or StartsWith(RequestPath, '/serilog-ui')"
    }
  }
]
```